# Why doesn't Comparable<T> include any type bound?

Tags: java, programming-languages, generics

Why do you think the definition of `Comparable<T>` lacks an upper bound on `T`?

That is, why is it not defined as:

```
Comparable<T extends Comparable<?>>
```

or

```
Comparable<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Wouldn't the latter two proposals be closer to the intended correct use of the interface?

The interface documentation starts with the following sentence, suggesting that it's intended to be used as `T implements Comparable<T>`:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it.

Is it just for backward compatibility with pre-generic code?

Comment: I don't know how you can say this is opinion based. It has the purely logical answer below

Comment: An answer that's being debated in the comments on its form, not its merit.   And it's unclear from the OP why the proposed definitions would be any better.

Comment: `T` doesn't need qualification for `Comparable<T>` to work. Your suggestions are limiting what T can be for no obvious reason.  `T` and `Comparable<T>` are different types. The latter offers a way to compare the former.  `Comparable<T>` places no requirement on `T` to be anything: `T` and `Comparable<T>` do not need to be in a (sub) class relationship

Comment: "The interface documentation starts with the following sentence, suggesting that it's intended to be used as `T implements Comparable<T>`" Yes, but there is no way to declare it in Java to guarantee that an implementing class `T` will implement `Comparable<T>` In the way you suggested declaring it, `interface Comparable<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, you can still declare `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>` and then `class Bar implements Comparable<Foo>`. That would be completely legal according to your declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Because you can have a type that is comparable to another type.

E.g.

```
class StringLike implements Comparable<String>
{
    int compareTo(String s) { /* something here */ }
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but you are abusing the interface, as proved by the fact that you can't use `StringLike` with any of the classes/methods that interact with `Comparable`, like `TreeSet` or `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: You certainly can't use it with anything wanting a `String`, but you can use it with anything wanting a `Comparable<String>`

Comment: Is there anything in the JDK that works with `Comparable<String>`? AFAIK everything needs a `T` that implements `Comparable<? super T>`.